# Непонятное полиморфное отношение в laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется:
модель Post

```
id - integer
title - string
body - text
```

модель Comment

```
id - integer
body - text
post_id - integer
commentable_type - string
```

В Comment настроено такое отношение

```
public function post(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}

public function expansion(): MorphTo
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Важно, если в обычных полиморфных отношениях commentable_type указывает родительскую модель, а post_id указывает идентификатор модели, то тут все сложнее. post_id действительно указывает на идентификатор родительской модели, а вот сама модель указанная в поле commentable_type является ссылается на дочерние модели CommentChildOne и CommentChildTwo, которых не существует в базе. Это просто какие-то синтетические модели расширяющие базовую Comment.

Если я в Post строю обычную связь

```
public function comments(): hasMany
{
     return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'post_id');
}
```

То получаю нужные записи, однако они имеют тип Comment. Возможно ли построить такое полиморфное отношение, что бы получать дочерние модели CommentChildOne, CommentChildTwo?

Comment: Что такое CommentChildOne? Один из комментов, принадлежащих какому то посту?

Comment: @DmitryWebsmith имя класса для конкретного экземпляра коммента к посту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть кому-то пригодится. Стандартными отношениями не получилось реализовать, переписывать Laravel это тоже не тот подход, который нужен. Так как CommentChildOne CommentChildTwo дочерние синтетически(которых нет в базе) классы класса Comment. То они обладают всеми теми же свойствами и методами, что и родитель.
Потому внутри класса Post были сделаны 2 функции, которые находят записи для данной записи.

```
public function getCommentChildOne(int $post_id)
{
    $commentChildOne = new CommentChildOne();
    return $commentChildOne::where('post_id', $post_id)->get();
}

public function getCommentChildTwo(int $post_id)
{
    $commentChildTwo = new CommentChildTwo();
    return $commentChildTwo::where('post_id', $post_id)->get();
}
```